# NodeJS read raw image file properties

Tags: node.js, file, cmd, properties

I am trying to read all the information related to the camera for a generic RAW image file though NodeJS ([Camera properties example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUBC0.png)). Although I've tried several ways, none of them leads to a solution. There are a few modules which works fine for JPEG/TIFF files, but none are generic.

Also trying the shell command

```
wmic datafile where name="C:\\path\\to\\file.ext"
```

does not help since the list of properties retrieved is not complete.

Comment: Problem solved using [exifr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exifr) module.Here below an example of the code used

Comment: I have removed your 'solution' edit from your question Marco. Please use the answer area, if you want to submit solutions to questions.